# Next.js: How to Prefetch Links on Hover Instead of Initial Render?"

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Hi I am using NextJS version 13.5.6 and using App router. My app around 50-60 links on initial render itself. Here is the snippet of my homepage.

```
<div className="nav">
  {nodes.map((node) => {
    return (
      <Link key={node.id} href={`availability/${node.slug}`}>
        {node.text}
      </Link>
    )
  })}
</div>
```

Now all those 50 links that are visible in the viewport are prefetched on the render itself. I don't want that behavior. Instead, I want to prefetch a link when a mouse is hovered on the link. Also I don't want to disable prefetching as on click of that link it takes more time to show the clicked link page. I just want prefetch on Mouseenter of that link. How to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useRouter()` and set its prefetching to false.

Notes: Prefetching is not enabled in development, only in production and only runs in the client component because it uses useRouter()

Here is an example:

```
"use client";

import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

const App = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <Link
      prefetch={false}
      href="/page/123"
      onMouseEnter={() => router.prefetch("/page/123")}
      className="cursor-pointer"
    >
      App
    </Link>
  );
};

export default App;
```